# How does one find an equivalent component?

Tags: components, prototyping, development

I was looking for an equivalent MOSFET and haven't had any success.

I'd like to know if are there any websites or software which gives a list of alternative equivalent components?

---

**Edit:**

The purpose of this question is not only for MOSFET's, but for any type of component.

I want to learn how to find equivalents (or similar) components without having the need to ask about specific components here.

Comment: What do you mean by equivalent - Are you trying to do some CMOS logic and need a near-perfect match, or do you just want to have the same package, Rds-on, voltage tolerances, and gate capacitance?

Comment: MOSFETs aren't that difficult to flip through at all the major manufacturer sites (Infineon, ST, IRF, Diodes, ON, Fairchild), they all have decent parametric filtering.

Comment: @reemrevnivek, the 2nd option.

Comment: "Decent" parametric filtering, but I have yet to see a manufacturer site with "good" parametric filtering.

Comment: It is hard to do, they do their best, and have to depend on suppliers letting them know what their specs are to a reasonable accuracy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

many distributors offer a cross reference search.

For something as simple as a mosfet i would probably just go to digikey, head to the mosfet section and enter the parameters in the digikey search options from the datasheet of the part you have.  Then compare datasheets for the results.

Comment: Digi-Key is probably the most convenient method, but don't pick exact values, but all those less than/greater than what you need.  If you're trying to replace an older part you are almost guaranteed to find a part with better performance/smaller package.

Answer (score 1):

Go to a vendor that might sell it, then check their cross reference.  For example for a National analog part I would go to TI, Linear and Analog Devices.  Also their FAE or the distributor's FAE.